# Phpunit integration testing symfony app - how to inject services into test?

Tags: integration-testing, symfony

I want to test a class by checking the real database data after function is executed.

I do not understand, how can I inject services which I need, for example some repository class.

So far I have written this:

```
namespace Tests\integration\Service\JourneyRunner\EmailConditionCheck;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;
use NG\Model\Journey\EmailConditionCheckRepositoryInterface;

class EmailConditionCheckServiceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    private $emailConditionCheckQueueRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EmailConditionCheckQueueRepositoryInterface $emailConditionCheckQueueRepository
    ) {
        $this->emailConditionCheckQueueRepository;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function testPrepareEmailContentForSending()
    {
        echo 'aaa';

        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);


    }
}
```

I added the test service to services.xml

```
<parameter key="tests.integration.service.journey_runner.email_condition_check.email_condition_check_service_test.class">tests\integration\Service\JourneyRunner\EmailConditionCheck\EmailConditionCheckServiceTest</parameter>

<service id="tests.integration.service.journey_runner.email_condition_check.email_condition_check_service_test" class="%tests.integration.service.journey_runner.email_condition_check.email_condition_check_service_test%">
            <argument type="service" id="ng.infrastructure.persistence.time_trigger_queue_repository" />
        </service>
```

I know that argument is wrong currently, but from the error I see that it does not get even the wrong argument - it gets nothing.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tests\integration\Service\JourneyRunner\EmailConditionCheck\EmailConditionCheckServiceTest::__construct() must be an instance of Tests\integration\Service\JourneyRunner\EmailConditionCheck\EmailConditionCheckQueueRepositoryInterface, none given, called in /var/www/api.notification.guru/ng-api-service/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 475 and defined in /var/www/api.notification.guru/ng-api-service/tests/integration/Service/JourneyRunner/EmailConditionCheck/EmailConditionCheckServiceTest.php:12
```

I tried to search for info, but I cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how, not inject, but geting a container gives result I want:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\integration\Service\JourneyRunner\EmailConditionCheck;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;
use NG\Model\Journey\EmailConditionCheckRepositoryInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

use NG\Model\Uuid;

class EmailConditionCheckServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{

    private $emailConditionCheckQueueRepository;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->container = static::$kernel->getContainer();

        $this->emailConditionCheckQueueRepository = $this->container->get('ng.infrastructure.persistence.email_condition_check_repository');
    }


    public function testPrepareEmailContentForSending()
    {

        $this->emailConditionCheckQueueRepository->get(Uuid::fromString('1'));

        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Also needed to create phpunit.xml - set the app directory. App directory is the one where AppKernel.php lies in your project as I understood.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And pass to phpunit command a parameter

```
--configuration=phpunit.xml
```